# yarn no longer present

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Been running my `npm start`, which uses `yarn`, over and over for the last 5 months and has been working since day dot.  I even see it in my Terminal history 10 lines above.

```
> yarn

yarn install v1.10.1
```

I killed my `npm start` process a moment ago, and now for some reason, I get this...

```
> yarn

sh: yarn: command not found
```

Yarn is no longer installed on my system...for some reason.  So I installed it and get the usual information that it's installed.

```
$ npm -g install yarn
+ yarn@1.12.3
added 1 package in 2.786s
```

But yarn still isn't installed and I'm still getting the same above issue.

I haven't done anything that would have messed up *yarn* in anyway (no installing/updating/removing of any packages), so I'm completely stumped as to what the heck happened.

Has anyone had this issue, know what it is and has a fix?

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of playing around, it seems that killing *yarn* in the process of it doing it's update, killed it's global link (e.g. `/usr/bin/yarn`) to it's binary.

So I ran the yarn application from it's full path, which I got from the `npm install -g yarn` (in my case `/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.12.0/bin/yarn`).

This then updated yarn, reinstalling the links and fixing it, and now it's all working.  :)